# Windows static vs dynamic linking: crash

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am new to windows programming and I am compiling some code that was designed to be compiled as a DLL.

I dont want to compile it as a DLL: I want to use it as a static lib (.lib). I found the following `#defines` in the code:

```
#  ifdef BUILD_DLL
#    ifdef __cplusplus
#      define __EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#      define __EXPORT extern __declspec(dllexport)
#    endif
#  else
#    ifdef __cplusplus
#      define __EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#    else
#      define __EXPORT extern __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif
```

Would it not be enough to delete this code and just do something like

```
#define __EXPORT
```

in order to link as static?

The problem is that, if I do that, the program compiles OK but crashes the first call to the DLL. What else do I have to do?

Comment: What happens if you leave the `extern "C"` and `extern` bits in and just remove the `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: In addition, make sure the static library and what it is being linked to (the application) use the same version of the C++ library (`/MD` vs. `/MT`).

Comment: It does not matter whether or not these attributes are used, they just provide hints.  The only thing that matters is how the code is linked.  You'll have to use a debugger to diagnose the "crash".

Comment: @Niall that did not do it.

Comment: @HansPassant I am looking through the debugger right now.

Comment: Ok, I managed to see the problem. DllMain() was performing required initializations that were not performed otherwise. I should have checked this function.